# How to write regular expression to find one or more digits separated by periods without returning the last period?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

How to write regular expression to find **between one and three digits separated by periods without returning the last period**? For example, find the string

```
1.1.
```

and it would also need to match

```
1.1
```

or simply

```
1
```

Likewise, it needs to support between one and three digits, so

```
11.11.11
```

and

```
111.111.111
```

need to work as well.

So..the string won't always end with a period, but it may. Further, if it does end with a period, don't return the last period (so, using a positive lookahead). So, `1.1.` if matched would return `1.1`

Here is what I have so far, but I am struggling to find a way to NOT return the last period:

```
(\d{1,3}\.?)+(?=(\Z|\s|\-|\;|\:|\?|\!|\.|\,|\)))
```

It is returning

```
6.6.
```

but I want it to return

```
6.6
```

Comment: I added explicitely the matching (or not) of a `.` at the end because you gave importace to it, but take in count that you can just ommit and just match `###.###.`...`.###` and will work for you.

Answer (score 4):

You require: match d.d.d.d. or d.d.dxxx, and regardless of whether it ends with a "." or not, always stop at the last d (never the dot).

What's wrong with just: `(\d(\.\d)*)`

If you want your dotted-digit string to be terminated by a set of characters, put a look-ahead after it, as you have in your question:

```
(\d(\.\d)*)(?=(\Z|\s|\-|\;|\:|\?|\!|\.|\,|\)))
```

If you also want it to match a stand-alone string (with or without the terminator), add a ? after the look-ahead:

```
(\d(\.\d)*)(?=(\Z|\s|\-|\;|\:|\?|\!|\.|\,|\)))?
```

For more than one digits, just replace \d with \d{1,3} etc.

Comment: This is helpful, however it still doesn't work for all scenarios, such as "1", "1.", "1.1", "1.1." and on.

Comment: I can see that you also want to match single digits.  Edited.

Comment: Beautiful! And I edited my question a bit. Here was my final expression:(\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3})*)(?=(\Z|\s|\-|\;|\:|\?|\!|\.|\,|\)))

Comment: No prob.  Glad to be of help.  I've edited the answer to include a comment on 1-3 digits.

Answer (score 2):

The regex `(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3})*)\.{0,1}` should work.

In the *Group 1* (if taken *Group 0* as the entire match) will be stored the string you want to keep, without the `.` at the end, in case it contains it.

It basically does:

- Start matching `1-3` digits
- Then match strings like `.d`, `.dd`, or `.ddd`
- If the match ends with a `.`, it won't take it because it isn't inside the group.

Do your tests and let us know if it works with all your examples.

**Edit:**

Replace `+` with `*`

Answer (score 0):

```
/\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3})*/
```

Quick explanation:

```
\d{1,3}  # Match 1-3 digits
(        # Start Capture Group 1
  \.       # Match '.'
  \d{1,3}  # Match 1-3 digits
)*       # End Capture Group 1 - match 0 or more times
```

Answer (score -3):

You can write your own Regular expression and test with dummy data on following Site:

http://myregexp.com/

Comment: How can *this* answer this question?

Comment: Its a suggestion to create the regular expression whihc the user can use.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was pretty close to spam